# Change the Datepacker Skins from Zebra

Tags: jquery, datepicker, skins

Is it possible to change the skin of this Zebra datepicker?
If yes, how?

Thanks!

[image]

https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker

Answer (score 0):

From the github page you have linked:

> has a default color scheme that blends-in well with almost any
>   design, and it’s easily customizable through the well-organized CSS
>   file; two additional themese are included, one of them being for use
>   with Twitter Bootstrap

So you can go with CSS to edit it or you can use one of the themes.